# 3D Max generate objects from animation frames, copy frames to viewport

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, autodesk

Is it possible to copy all animation frames into separate objects in the viewport?

I am already using the Path Deformation and the Array tools, but they cannot (as far I know) animate materials. Also, their output cannot be edited with the curve editor??

Example:
I have a 30 frame animation of a rotating box moving along a path. Instead I would like 30 boxes in the viewport. Each one, a copy of its respective keyframe.

Sort of like the classic video technique of creating trails from moving objects. I know it can be done in After Effects, but I want to actual 3d models from my own custom animation frames, in the scene and not the results from Path Deformation and Array. Then I can work on them as a still image.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct forum for this question, perhaps http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the object and use this maxscript code:

```
for i = 1 to 30 do at time i snapshot $
```

It will create a collapsed copy of the mesh at each frame.

Comment: This worked exactly as I imagined. Thank you very much. This really puts me in an advanced position for the art I am creating.

Comment: Hey thanks for that info. I didn't realise I could click the tick image. I had always tried the arrow up button, but never had enough reputation. Thanks again. I will go and accept all other answers on my account now.